# Connecting a vertex to middle of an edge with GraphPlot?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

using `GraphPlot` I'd like to make directed arrow connecting a vertex (node) to the middle of an edge but couldn't find a way. Is this even possible using `GraphPlot` or other graphics-related commands in Mathematica.

Basically I'd like to plot enzyme-substrate network and so like to connect node E (enzyme) to an edge connecting substrate S to product P, and scale-up for all Enzyme-Substrate-Product combination.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Sounds like you will need to add a new vertex to the graph and connect it to the two nodes of the edge of interest (and to the additional node you mentioned).

Comment: Thanks David, this is exactly what I was doing and it does work but the network looks a bit messy since the new node doesn't line up with S and P on a straight line. Is there a way to force the new node to line up with S and P?

Comment: Normally you can address this through `GraphLayout`.  But for fine control, as I believe you want in the present example, you'll need to also examine the documentation for `VertexCoordinates`, and `VertexCoordinateRules`.

Comment: And `SetProperties`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

---

**The initial graph**

```
g = Graph[{"S", "P", "E"}, {"S" \[UndirectedEdge] "P"}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
ImagePadding -> 25]
```

[image: g]

---

**1. Add the new node**.

```
g1 = VertexAdd[g, "NewNode"]
```

[image: g1]

---

**2. Add 3 new edges**.

```
g2 = EdgeAdd[ g1, {"S" \[UndirectedEdge] "NewNode", 
"NewNode" \[UndirectedEdge] "P", "NewNode" \[UndirectedEdge] "E"}]
```

[image: g2]

---

**3. Remove SP edge.**

```
g3 = EdgeDelete[g2, {"S" \[UndirectedEdge] "P"}]
```

[image: g3]

---

**4. Tidy up the graph layout**

```
g4=SetProperty[g3, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}]
```

[image]